Error when using inputs_embeds with generate method
I'm encountering a problem when trying to use inputs_embeds to pass the embedding to my model:
ValueError: You passed `inputs_embeds` to `.generate()`, but the model class LlamaForCausalLM doesn't have its forwarding implemented. See the GPT2 implementation for an example (https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/pull/21405), and feel free to open a PR with it!

Can someone help me understand what is going on and how to fix this issue?
I have an embedding with the shape torch.Size([1, 46, 4096]) and I want to pass it to my model. Here is my code:
if True:
    from unsloth import FastLanguageModel
    model, tokenizer = FastLanguageModel.from_pretrained(
        model_name = "/content/drive/My Drive/finetuneunslothllama", 
        max_seq_length = max_seq_length,`your text`
        dtype = dtype,
        load_in_4bit = load_in_4bit,
    )
    FastLanguageModel.for_inference(model) # Activer native 2x faster inference

outputs = model.generate(inputs_embeds=embeddings, max_new_tokens=64, use_cache=True)

generated_text = tokenizer.batch_decode(outputs, skip_special_tokens=True)
print(generated_text)


The issue you're encountering is related to the fact that the LlamaForCausalLM model from the transformers library doesn't have its forward method implemented to handle inputs_embeds when calling .generate(). This means that, unlike other models such as GPT2, LlamaForCausalLM cannot directly accept embeddings in the way you're trying to use them.
Here's a breakdown of what's happening and how you might resolve the issue:
Understanding the Issue
inputs_embeds Usage: When you're using inputs_embeds, you're providing precomputed embeddings to the model instead of raw input tokens. Normally, this would be passed to the model’s forward method, which processes the embeddings instead of the usual token IDs.
LlamaForCausalLM Limitation: The error message indicates that the LlamaForCausalLM model class in transformers doesn’t have an implementation for handling inputs_embeds during generation. This is because the .generate() method of the LlamaForCausalLM model isn't designed to work with precomputed embeddings.
How to Fix It
To resolve this, you have a few options:
Use a Different Model: If feasible, consider using a model that supports inputs_embeds during generation. Models like GPT2ForCausalLM have this functionality implemented.
Custom Generation Loop: If you need to use LlamaForCausalLM, you may need to implement a custom generation loop. This involves manually running the model step-by-step using the precomputed embeddings.
Modify the Model: If you have the capacity to modify the model code, you could implement the logic for handling inputs_embeds in the LlamaForCausalLM's generation method, similar to how it's done in the GPT2ForCausalLM model. However, this requires a deeper understanding of the model's internals.

Thank you for your response. Since I cannot replace the model in my project and I have already conducted tests and improvements on the embeddings, could you suggest an alternative method to integrate embeddings with this model? I am looking for a solution that allows me to use the embeddings while sticking with the current model.
